# Expected Type Bytes and got str instead udp client error

Tags: python, sockets

```
    import socket
    
    target_host = "127.0.0.1"
    target_port = 80
    
    # create a socket object
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    
    # send some data
    client.sendto("AAABBBCCC", (target_host, target_port))
    
    # receive some data
    data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)
    print(data)
```

I receive this error when running this copy and pasted code from a pentesting book:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\cLappy\PycharmProjects\Coffee Machine\.idea\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "<ipython-input-2-576063807716>", line 1, in <module>
        runfile('E:/Pycharm Projects/Pentesting/UDP Client.py', wdir='E:/Pycharm Projects/Pentesting')
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
        pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
        exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
      File "E:/Pycharm Projects/Pentesting/UDP Client.py", line 10, in <module>
        client.sendto("AAABBBCCC", (target_host, target_port))
    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I would like to know what I can replace "AAABBBCCC" with so I can begin my free lancing pentesting journey.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could make the "AAABBBCCC" in the flagged line 10 using bytes instead of string - maybe add the letter b? like b"AAABBBCCC" ... and see if you spice up the copy-pasta (and only target systems you are explicitly allowed to target of course, right? Right! The current target localhost looks OK ...)

Comment: I tried that and I receive another error on line 13 called ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. Am open to trying other things, please help.

Comment: Well, maybe add that to the question (what service listening on port 80, the traceback of the new error, ...) until now the question was focused bytes instead of str, debugging a complex client server scenario is maybe not well suited for the question answer format of the site?

Comment: This is code copy and pasted from a pentesting book, I'm just wondering what can be replaced with aaabbbccc to make the client function

Comment: Seems like there is no UDP server on 127.0.0.1 port 80

Comment: Thank you for that, I will try initalizing a server and if it works I'll set it as solved

Answer (score 0):

Edit the sendto func:

```
client.sendto(("AAABBBCCC").encode()(target_host.encode(),target_port))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.